# how to get top n count by each group in hive

Tags: hadoop, count, hive, sql-order-by, hql

there are some datas like following format

```
url                    |    ip
-----------------------+-----------------
http://aaa.com/        |    1.1.1.1
http://bbb.com/        |    1.2.3.5
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.6
http://ddd.com/        |    1.2.3.4
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.2
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.2
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.2
http://aaa.com/        |    1.1.1.1
http://bbb.com/        |    1.2.3.5
```

I am now try to count ip column which is the top n ip in each group by url. like

```
url                    |    ip           |    ipcount
-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------
http://aaa.com/        |    1.1.1.1      |    2
http://aaa.com/        |    5.6.7.8      |    1
http://bbb.com/        |    1.2.3.5      |    2
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.2      |    3
http://ccc.com/        |    1.1.1.6      |    1
http://ddd.com/        |    1.2.3.4      |    1
```

please tell me how can i write a HQL for implement this in a Hive ?

update: sorry i forgot to notice that i should get the top N records in each group like  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try: `SELECT url, ip, COUNT(url) FROM tbl GROUP BY url, ip`

Comment: ah sorry, I have forgot to notice that i want to get the Top N records in each group... thanks for answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, ip, count(*) as ipcount
from table t
group by url, ip
```

This should work in your case.